# Compound conditions in an if statement

Tags: compiler-errors

I have two integers called range1 and range 2 and I want to use them in an if statementas follows

```
if((range1 || range2)>20 && (range1 || range2)<=50)
Console.WriteLine("some Message");
```

I get an error saying I cannot us the || operator in an int && int comparison. 
I was trying to avoid coding for the larger of range1 or range 2 as the values can be either positive or negative. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Om

Answer (score 2):

`||` doesn't work like that.  It's a logical operator that can only operate on *booleans*.

Instead, you can write `if (range1 > 20 || range2 > 20)`